# Get the highest number and return it´s own record as "representative of the group"

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to make a query, I'm trying to get the grouping of some fields but bring me the record with the highest index. This is my example [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4985e4/27)

I tried with

```
SELECT F. * FROM FOLIOS F
GROUP BY FOLIO
```

But this brings me the record with Id 1, Index 1 of folio 10, and I am looking for the record with Id 2, index 2 of folio 10 as "representative of the group"

I also tried

```
SELECT F. * FROM FOLIOS F WHERE MAX (F.FOLIO)
GROUP BY FOLIO;
SELECT F. * FROM FOLIOS F
GROUP BY FOLIO HAVING MAX (F.FOLIO);
```

But I do not get the result.

You can also help me if the date is the most recent but I need the complete record not only the field

Can you support me with the doubt?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT F. *
FROM FOLIOS F
ORDER BY F.FOLIO DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I believe he wants all the rows, but the id he expects the highest index of the group by 
----------     id:2 folio:10 and max:2      https://gyazo.com/169b5ca15e7874f7b34aad33f0c95f58

Comment: @Gordon I believe he wants to return all the records belonging to the same folio group which contains the `MAX()` value for `index`. At least that is my read of it.